# .NET 4.0 и Log4Net - не пишет в файл

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

Не могу разобраться почему не пишет логи в файл.
Есть файл конфига:

```
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>  
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="Logs/logistic.log" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} [%t] %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Инициализирую логгер в файле Logger.cs

```
using log4net;

[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch=false)]


namespace ReloadDataForJurist
    {
    public static class Logger
        {

        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(string.Empty);

        /// <summary>
        /// Лог
        /// </summary>
        public static ILog Log
            {
            get { return log; }
            }
        }
    }
```

Ну и добавляю в логгер записи:

```
    Logger.Log.Info("Подключение к базе данных успешно проверено");
```

Файл не создает, в файл не пишет, ошибок никаких не выкидывает.
Чего не хватает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Шаг первый

[Включите отладку](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html):

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

У вас в консоли и debug trace появятся все сообщения из потрохов log4net. По умолчанию log4net полностью заглатывает все исключения из соображений, что приложение не должно падать из-за отвалившегося логирования.

## Шаг второй

Удалите log4net. Это ископаемые экскременты мамонта. Библиотека практически не обновляется. Пора переходить на что-то посвежее, например, NLog.

Comment: Спасибо. Сел за 10 минут все переписал на NLog.

Comment: И что значит, что она не обновляется? Типа из-за этого она плохая? Может как раз наоборот - не обновляется так как все допилено и работает хорошо?